# In python If I use one venv with two project folder. does it makes my project slower?

Tags: python

In python If I use one venv with two project folder. does it makes my project slower while run?

Comment: have you tested to see what happens?

Comment: yes, nothing happend to me

Comment: Then you have answered your own question.

Comment: Am I right??????

Comment: Using a virtual environment is no different than having Python installed under `/usr/bin` versus `/usr/local/bin` It's just a different location for the binary and its associated library.

Comment: thank you very much!